# Is there a way to apply all files in a folder using Openshift cli recursively?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, yaml, openshift

I have a folder of yaml files and I need to apply all files into an Openshift cluster using one command. I know that this can be done via kubectl. Can this be also achieved using oc cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the same way as you can do it with `kubectl`:

```
oc apply -f your/folder/with/yamls
```

If you want it recursively, you can use the `--recursive` flag:

```
oc apply -f your/folder/with/yamls --recursive
```